# SendMouseWheelEvent does not work on subsequent page loads

Tags: python, cefpython

I'm trying to use SendMouseWheelEvent to pass mouse scrolls into the browser, but it is only working on the first page load. Any subsequent pageloads after that, it does not work, unless the browser is interferred with actual mouse scroll.
I've prepared the following script. The "errorrep" is actually the name of the script itself, as "errorrep.py", into which I'm assigning the browser as "mybrowser".
How can I have the browser correctly work with SendMouseWheelEvent on subsequent pageloads?
cefpython version is 66.1.

```
"""
SendMouseWheelEvent is correctly performed on the first page load. On any pageloads after that, it does not seem to work, but it works again when the actual mouse device performs a scroll on the webpage

'# test 1' which does a javascript code 'scrollBy', works on every pageload.
'# test 2' which does a SendMouseWheelEvent, only works on first page load.

"""

from cefpython3 import cefpython as cef
import time
from threading import Thread
import errorrep

mybrowser = None

def main():
    cef.Initialize()
    browser = cef.CreateBrowserSync(url="https://stackoverflow.com/")
    browser.SetClientHandler(LoadHandler())
    errorrep.mybrowser = browser
    cef.MessageLoop()
    del browser
    cef.Shutdown()


class LoadHandler(object):
    def OnLoadingStateChange(self, browser, is_loading, **_):
        if not is_loading:
            Thread(target=test).start()


def test():
  print("Page loading is complete!")
  for i in range(5):
    print('scrolling')
    # test 1
    errorrep.mybrowser.ExecuteJavascript(jsCode="""scrollBy(0,25)""")
    # test 2
    # errorrep.mybrowser.SendMouseWheelEvent(0,0,0,-120, cef.EVENTFLAG_NONE)
    time.sleep(1)
  print('opening new page, clicking on the logo link')
  errorrep.mybrowser.ExecuteJavascript(jsCode="""document.getElementsByClassName('s-topbar--logo js-gps-track')[0].click();""")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```